# Having trouble with for loop printing everything

Tags: python, list, if-statement, input, while-loop

I'm still fairly new to python and I have a project that I am doing that is about paths and files. Unfortunately, I cannot post my code for that project or else I can get into trouble. So I have made a practice problem that is similar to what I'm hoping to execute with my code and I'm wondering if someone could please help me out because I've been stuck on this for a few days.

Okay so what I want to do is after verifying the first input and entering the second input is to print all sentences within the list L that contained the second input inside of it. Ex. if I have a list called

```
dog_sentences = ['dogs are cute', 'dogs are loyal', 'hi cat', 'dogs rule']
```

if my second input is the word dogs. I want it to print out all the sentences within the list that contain the word dogs. So what I want to print out is the following.

```
dogs are cute
dogs are loyal
dogs rule
```

That is what I want to be able to print in the shell. So these are the practice problems that I've made and have tried in two different ways.

this is the list:

```
L=['hi there', 'it was nice to say hi', 'saying hi this many times is awkward',
   'hey I can also say hola', 'no need to say hi']
```

First way:

```
while True:
    match = input().strip()
    for sentence in L:
        if match == 'Next' + ' ' + 'step':
            print('match')
            new_word_match = input().strip()
            if new_word_match in sentence:
                print(sentence)
                break
        else:
            print('error')
```

but in the shell it just print outs the first sentence in the list and then continues to output error each time I click enter.

second way:

```
while True:
    match = input().strip()
    for sentence in L:
        print(sentence)
    if match == 'Next' + ' ' + 'step':
        print('match')
        new_word_match = input().strip()
        if new_word_match in sentence:
            print(sentence)
            break
    else:
        print('error')
```

The shell will only give me the final sentence which is 'no need to say hi'. But what I want to print is

```
hi there
it was nice to say hi
saying hi this many times is awkward
no need to say hi
```

If someone could please help me out I would really appreciate it and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So do you need to take these inputs continuously? You have `while True` in both examples. In the second one there is `break` but the first doesn't have any for the `while` loop.

Comment: Since my original problem is about paths. I need the while loop because if the path doesn't exist then I need to print the word error and then repeat the process of asking for a path until it's valid. It's the reason that I'm using the while loop. My apologies for not writing that sooner.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ["god is there", "human are there", "nobody there"]
string = str(raw_input("which word r u lookin for: "))
for i in range(0, len(l)):
    if(string in str(l[i])):
        print(l[i])
```

Even I am new to Python..Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to repeat this process. Code below should work:

```
input1 = input().strip()
match_string = "Next Step"
if input1 == match_string:
    input2 = input().strip()
    for sentence in sentences:
         if input2 in sentence:
             print(sentence)
```

If you need to repeat it:

```
while True:
   input1 = input().strip()
   match_string = "Next Step"
   if input1 == match_string:
      input2 = input().strip()
      for sentence in sentences:
           if input2 in sentence:
               print(sentence)

   ....some condition to break out....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your question. I'm new to Python as well and might just as well not be able to see the full picture. This is what I came up with.

```
searched_words = input("word you want to see in text: ")
for i in L:
    if searched_words in i:
        print(i)
```

If you want to make a continuous loop:

```
ans = True
while ans == True:
    searched_words = raw_input("word you want to see in text: ")
    for i in L:
        if searched_words in i:
            print(i)
    check = raw_input("Do you wish to continue searching for words in the list(y/n)?")
    if check == 'n': 
        ans = False
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I apologize what I was trying to do is whatever is written for the second input to check if it is within the list somewhere. And if it was found within a string or more, then to print only those that had that word. so like the dogs example. If my second input the word dogs then only three strings should be printed out. My second code get's the closest cause it prints the last thing in the list but it won't print every string with the word dog in it. Sorry I hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex module instead (represented with `re`). For example:

```
import re

dog_sentences = ['dogs are cute', 'dogs are loyal', 'hi cat', 'dogs rule']
for i in range(0, len(dog_sentences)):
    m = re.match("dogs", dog_sentences[i])
    if m is not None:
        print dog_sentences[i]
```

`import re` first will import the regex module, which is required in this program. `for i in range(0, len(dog_sentences)):` will then start a `for` loop that will help conduct the search of every single item in the list. `len()` is used as the length of the list. Since the last number is one less than what is written, it will be useful to search through the list using `dog_sentences[i]`.

```
m = re.match("dogs", dog_sentences[i])
```

The first argument is the string or pattern you want to find in your string, which is your next item. If there is no match, `m` is equal to `None`.

```
if m is not None:
    print dog_sentences[i]
```

If there is a match (`m` is not equal to `None`), then print the appropriate item that contains the string within it.